# Identifying Android game seen in Fast & Furious 7 movie?

Tags: android, game-identification

This is a screenshot from the movie Fast & Furious 7. Tej is playing this game just before doing the air drop mission.

[image: game of a character floating above a target]

Does anyone know what this game is?

Comment: That's definitely not a real game.
1) they would have to buy the rights to show the game on screen before doing so.
2) just look at it, would it really say what level you were on in the bottom Right All the time?
3) He is on level 7 and only has 2 coins. that doesn't seem like a realistic mechanic.
4) it looks like thats a speedometer in the bottom right, why would it be so low if he is falling from the sky, he has no parachute open yet. Surely if that was a real game you would get faster. you'd definitely not be going at 1/3rd full speed 600ft from the floor.

Comment: I see.. It's a mock game just for one scene..

Comment: unfortunatly yes, thats more than likely. I remember the day I realised they did this was the day I found out that the "game" in the music video for Red Hot Chilli Peppers - Californication, wasn't a real game :(
Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlUKcNNmywk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a mock game inspired by  [AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! – A Reckless Disregard for Gravity](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dejobaangames.awesome) to me.

Comment: That was my guess too.

Comment: The image provided is far less polished than the game is. I doubt that's the right game.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau i doubt the game in the picture exists, but I'm pretty confident it's supposed to reference AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!

Comment: Why wouldn't it exists?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I rarely see actual games (that are not massively mainstream like cod) in mainstream media, a lot of fake games or applications, even fake OS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong. The game this answer mentions does not show your character in-game, while the game played in the question does. The HUD also is different.

Comment: I just watched a gameplay video of AaaaaAAaaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! Force = Mass x Acceleration and seems like this answer is wrong

Comment: user4903602 seems to be aware that the being searched for propably isn't a real game. I think he's trying to say "the mock-game in the film was *inspired by*". Altought this isn't very clear from the answer itself.

Comment: @DJ Pirtu, would they create a mock game just like that? It doesn't seem to have any significance in the movie.

Comment: @BasimRauf My memory is fuzzy, but I think I've seen a fake game being used in a movie more ofthen than a real one. Most likely they just created a few seconds of game looking CGI, not an actual game.

Comment: @BasimRauf it's very common, try to notice it, you'll see it pop up more than thought

Comment: @user4903602 It's true that sometimes happens, but I've seen real games used plenty of times as well.

Answer (score -2):

It's Man or Monsters. It's available on Steam.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't look anything like what I assume is '(Super) Man or Monster'. Can you explain why you think that's the game the OP is referring to?